# Не меняется язык после перезапуска приложения

Tags: java, android

Имеется приложение, состоящее из нескольких activity.
В данном случае MainScreen и Setting.
В Setting есть выбор языка, он работает. После нажатия на кнопку язык меняется, activity перезапускается и все приложение на нужном мне языке. 
Выбор пользователя я сохраняю в настройки.

Приложение рано или поздно будет выключено. При включении, запускается MainScreen, читается файл настроек и язык изменяется на заранее сохраненный. 
// Так должно быть в моем представлении, и так это реализовано. Однако при перезапуске ничего не изменяется и не могу понять почему. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот для Setting

```
Button ExitBtn;
Button ChangeLang_Ru;
Button ChangeLang_En;
Button ChangeLang_De;



// Инициализируем файл настроек
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_LANG = "LANG"; // Параметр языка

SharedPreferences mSettings;
// Отключено = 0
Integer audio_on = 0;

Locale myLocale;
String lang_set = "ru";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hideStatusBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);

    ExitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExitBtn);
    ExitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    ChangeLang_Ru = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeLang_Ru);
    ChangeLang_Ru.setOnClickListener(this);

    ChangeLang_En = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeLang_En);
    ChangeLang_En.setOnClickListener(this);

    ChangeLang_De = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeLang_De);
    ChangeLang_De.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Инициализируем настройки
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);




}



//Слушаем кнопки, выполняем переход
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ExitBtn:
            finish();
            Intent menu_intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(menu_intent);
            break;
        case R.id.ChangeLang_Ru:
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = mSettings.edit();
            editor1.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_LANG, "ru");
            editor1.apply();
            setLocale("ru");

            break;
        case R.id.ChangeLang_En:
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = mSettings.edit();
            editor2.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_LANG, "en");
            editor2.apply();
            setLocale("en");

            break;
        case R.id.ChangeLang_De:
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = mSettings.edit();
            editor3.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_LANG, "de");
            editor3.apply();
            setLocale("de");
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}

// Меняет язык
public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

}

И соответственно для MainScreen

```
   // Инициализируем файл настроек
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_LANG = "LANG"; // Параметр языка
    SharedPreferences mSettings;

    String lang_set = "ru";

    Locale myLocale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Инициализируем настройки
        mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_LANG)) {
            lang_set = mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_LANG, "");
        }

        switch(lang_set) {
            case "ru":
                setLocale("ru");
                break;
            case "en":
                setLocale("en");
                break;
            case "de":
                setLocale("de");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hideStatusBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {

        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        //Эта часть здесь по всей видимости лишняя
        //Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
        //startActivity(refresh);
    }
```

В манифесте для всех activity прописано следующее:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

Comment: покажите, как вы инициализируете `mSettings` в обеих местах. Возможно, это 2 совершенно не связанных `SharedPreferences`

Comment: @metalurgus обновил описание.

Comment: следующий уточняющий вопрос: Вы не выложили константы APP_PREFERENCES и APP_PREFERENCES_LANG. Вы уверены на 100%, что их значения в разных Activity совпадают?

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы запускаете ту же активити после смены языка, но до перезаписывания значения в преференсы, вместо сначала обновления прееренсов а потом простого пересоздания активти чрез `recreate()` . И ваше значение из преференсов нигде не используется, хотя должно бы в самом наччале `onCreate` примениться.

Comment: @metalurgus да я подумал что это так же необходимо, и добавил константы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб изменил поведение кнопок.  К сожалению никак не повлияло. Значение не используется в `MainScreen` или `Setting` ?

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, а, в маин вижу. Может это убрать? android:configChanges="locale"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вообще немного странно. После добавления изменений на которые здесь указали, приложение перестало запускаться, будто бесконечный цикл перезапусков. Но, удалив строчку с пересозданием activity в MainScreen все стало на свои места. Функционал смены языка полностью работает. Обновил описание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в MainScreen язык изменяете после того как уже всё на дефолтном отобразили. Вызывайте `setLocale` до `setContentView` а лучше наверное и до `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: переместил всю конструкцию чтения настроек и смены языка до `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` ничего к сожалению не изменилось :(

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, может я не правильно вас понял?
Что самое обидное стоит зайти в настройки и язык сразу такой какой нужно, а до этого никак.

Comment: хм, ну 100% вариант это переместить установку языка в класс приложения. Если у вас его ещё нет, то создайте класс унаследованный от Application и у него в onCreate задайте язык как вы это делали в активити. Ну и не забудьте прописать ваш новый класс в манифесте в теге application в атрибуте `android:name`

Comment: уже разобрался. Точнее разобрался не до конца, однако все работает. Спасибо :)